# Makefile pattern rule that matches either .c or .s

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to combine these two pattern rules into one?  (They are identical, except one is for C files and the other for assembly.)

```
$(USR_OBJ)/%.o: $(USR_SRC)/%.c $(OS_SRC)/*.h 
    $(elfCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(OS_SRC)

$(USR_OBJ)/%.o: $(USR_SRC)/%.s $(OS_SRC)/*.h
    $(elfCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(OS_SRC)
```

The duplication isn't terrible; but, it just bugs me that there is only one letter difference between the two rules.  (And, unlike [Makefile implicit rules matching .c OR .cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982232/makefile-implicit-rules-matching-c-or-cp), I don't expect my flags will diverge.)

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  The best you can do (IMO) is use a variable for the recipe to avoid some duplication:

```
COMPILE.o = $(elfCC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I $(OS_SRC)

$(USR_OBJ)/%.o: $(USR_SRC)/%.c $(OS_SRC)/*.h 
        $(COMPILE.o)

$(USR_OBJ)/%.o: $(USR_SRC)/%.s $(OS_SRC)/*.h
        $(COMPILE.o)
```

It's much more efficient to do the wildcard one time, rather than redo it every time the rule is matched:

```
HEADERS := $(wildcard $(OS_SRC)/*.h)

$(USR_OBJ)/%.o: $(USR_SRC)/%.c $(HEADERS)
        $(COMPILE.o)

$(USR_OBJ)/%.o: $(USR_SRC)/%.s $(HEADERS)
        $(COMPILE.o)
```

Even better would be to use one of the auto-dependency generation methods so that changing one header doesn't recompile the world (unless you know that all your `.c` and `.s` files include all the headers all the time).

There are options like using a `define` and a `foreach` etc. but for only two rules they're overkill and will leave your makefile much *less* readable.  If you had 5 or 10 variations maybe it would be worthwhile.